# how to solve eclipse perspective error?

Tags: android, eclipse

I add my error in below snap.I am working with android and I have Eclipse Indigo Service Release 1 version.When Any Error comes it give me in java perspective.How to close it and only see When i change my DDMS perspective ,I stop it in java perspective.

[image]

Comment: click and drag the logcat tab near to console tab and drop it there.

Comment: its give me icon near console and when i close it and rerun its same problem ,I want to final solution

Comment: I am using Eclipse 3.5.2, and I find you can add/remove any view to any perspective(window->show view). Perhaps I didn't unserstand your problem.

Comment: nop see i answer for perfect solution....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable the automated logcat popup by going to `Window -> Preferences -> Android -> LogCat` and unchecking *Display logcat view when there are messages from an application in the workspace*. Then just close the subwindow, it should stay closed until you switch the perspective.